# how to set media (eg, portrait, landscape) for testing

Tags: media-queries

I am using media selectors in my css:
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { /* etc */
I test layout in Safari, and then the iPad simulator.
But Safari seems fixed in landscape. How to tell Safari my media should be portrait?

That is so that I can test the layout when the orientation is landscape.

I found a media property of a styleSheets object, see
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-MediaList
but, at least in Safari or the iPad simulator, that list is empty. So adding a new media string to the list probably isn't the answer.

I tried setting width and height in the viewport meta tag to a hasty portrait shape:

Nope. media is still landscape orientation.

Argh, i do not want to make special testing versions of the css.

Comment: Besides, that's backwards; I think the MediaList sets what media the styleSheet applies to.